# Probable IIS changes after update

Tags: iis, scheduled-task, windows-update, settings

We have developed a module which enters Windows Scheduled tasks in on our server that are calling KeepAlive pages on different servers. Normally everything went fine, but since 21-07-2011 on 17:00 all our KeepAlive pages generate errors. Those errors are because on IIS level the defaultLanguage of the different websites that run there are set to VB instead of c#. Has there be any update or whatsoever that can mess up a setting like this? How can it be that suddenly the standard language on IIS level has been changed to VB instead of C#?
Hope anyone has a bright idea on this issue. I'm guessing perhaps some update has been run (our machine installs updates automatically). Can anyone track this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The default *defaultLanguage* is set at the IIS root level (ASP.NET -> .NET Compliation) and inherited by all websites unless redefined there.

In your scenario there seem to be two possible causes:

1) The *defaultLanguage* was changed at the IIS root level. Since VB is the preset *defaultLangauge* it would mean that your *defaultLanguage* was set to C# at the root level (and changed at/around the date you mentioned). It would be relatively easy to reproduce an update reverting your selected *defaultLanguage* C# back to VB.

2) All your sites did override the unchanged *defaultLanguage* set at IIS root in their own web.config and this configuration was modified in every web.config.

You could investigate if there are differences between websites inheriting *defaultLanguage* and websites overriding it via web.config-